# Passing Variable from one website page to another website page without using QueryString

Tags: java, asp.net, cross-platform, query-string

This question is related to a previous question 
[Passing Variable from page to page using ASP.NET (C#) without using QueryString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103890/passing-variable-from-page-to-page-using-asp-net-c-without-using-querystring)

The difference in my case is that the request is coming from a different website (in java) to my website (in asp.net). I do not want the variable to appear in url.

Any suggestions !!

To explain my scenario, we are making a webpage(plugin), which can be called from any other website. To authenticate request, i am looking for a mechanism when other website will pass id & auth-key to my page. This i can use to authenticate the request. I do not want these variable to be visible.

Comment: Can you send a POST request instead of a GET?

Comment: Why don't you want to store the data in the querystring?

Comment: Well we are making a webpage(plugin), which can be called from any other website. To authenticate request, i am looking for a mechanism when other website will pass id & auth-key to my page. This i can use to authenticate the request. I do not want these variable to be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `POST` operation would work.  The variable would still be part of the request, but it would not be readily visible to the user.  I say "readily" visible because it won't be part of the requested URL, but it would be visible if they were to use a tool like Firebug.  Short of sharing a database or some other form of "out-of-band" communication, I'm not sure it can be done any other way...

Comment: Thanks for answer Chris! as i will be getting variables like (e.g. id & auth-key) from another/java website, i need to provide the java people some out-of-band communication mechanism. Can you suggest something here?

Comment: @Sharjeel well, you'll need some other form of communication.  This will have to be something like a database or a shared file system.  There are a number of systems that do authentication in a similar manner but do allow the auth key to be visible to the user.  I would strongly suggest examining your system to see if there's a way to make that possible.  It's really going to be your best bet.  Another option would be to look into something like a single sign on system or oauth.

Answer (score 1):

Well as chris mentioned doing a POST  is the best way to achieve this. Else you can look at using javascript to achieve the same. Its pretty easy to use JS libraries to achieve the same.

Some of them that come to my mind are
a) Jquery
b) YUI
c) EXT (now Sencha i guess)

But I would definitely recommend jquery.

With jquery you have apis to do post operations. here is more on how to achieve the same. 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the jQuery option, i would pass it to the java website people.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done without a query string. I know sessions won't work because sessions cannot be shared between Java, Asp, Asp.net, Php etc..., at least not nativly. If you have a database where you store the sessions, you can always use a session id in a query string and therefore simulate cross-language-sessions.